# How can I measure in milliseconds mousemove on the page?

Tags: javascript

How i can measure in milliseconds mousemove on the page? So, i want `alert('Message');` when user move mouse on the page more than 5 seconds.

```
var showtime = 5000; // milliseconds
var currenttime = 0; // milliseconds

document.onmousemove = function(e){
    // How i can measure time? (increase `currenttime` in milliseconds)
    if(showtime <= currenttime) {
        alert('Message');
    }
};
```

Comment: Do a quick google for setTimeOut in JS and let me know what questions come up from that.

Comment: @Jhecht but i want measure how long user move mouse on the page and if this variable more than 5 seconds i alert message.

Comment: You need to define what you mean by the user moving a mouse on the page more than 5 seconds. Do you mean *continuously* for five seconds or do you mean for a *total* of five seconds? ? Even if the user is moving the mouse very quickly, there will probably be a few milliseconds where the page won't register mouse movement, so you need a throttle.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, i mean total of five seconds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to do something like this, using a throttle (I used 300ms), and then canceling the timeout etc.

```
var showtime = 5000; // milliseconds
var currenttime = 0; // milliseconds
var timer;

document.onmousemove = function(e){
    currenttime = currenttime ? currenttime : Date.now();

    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        currenttime = 0;
    }, 300);

    if ( (Date.now() - currenttime) > showtime) {
        currenttime = 0;
        alert('Message');
    }
};
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/dym2zf4t/)

---

For a total time the mouse has been moved, the principle is the same, you'll still have to throttle, and add up the time the mouse moved. This fires after the last the time the mouse moved, and the value exceeds 5 seconds

```
var showtime  = 5000; // milliseconds
var starttime = 0;    // milliseconds
var totaltime = 0;
var timer;

document.onmousemove = function(e){
    starttime = starttime ? starttime : Date.now();
    clearTimeout(timer);

    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        totaltime += Date.now() - starttime;
        starttime = 0;
    }, 300);

    if (totaltime > showtime) {
        alert("Message");
    }
};
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/dym2zf4t/2/)

Comment: +1 - Smart to use the Date in order to facilitate this.

Comment: I was going to code something, then I saw your answer. No point in 2 people posting the same code.